# Integrating a rails app into WordPress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, integration

I have a client with a WordPress static website who wants to integrate the Rails app we have created into their platform so that when they click on a button, they reach the Rails app and the domain looks something like `www.client.com/rails-app`. I've looked at some plug-ins to integrate it inside the WordPress but most of them seem really outdated. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thank you !! :)

Answer (score 2):

In your Apache/Nginx conf, you can add a virtual host with server_name `www.client.com/rails-app` pointing to your rails-app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where can I find that file within WordPress?

Comment: > Where can I find that file within WordPress?

Comment: > Where can I find that file within WordPress?

No idea about wordpress.  Are you hosting Wordpress yourself? If not, other option can be adding a CNAME record to your DNS settings, then you can have subdomain rails-app.client.com point to the rails app.